# Flex Layout Grid formatting

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

This is my current grid formatting:

[image: Format I have]

Code:

```
          <div fxLayout="row wrap">
            <img
              class="component-logo"
              fxFlex="1 1 calc(20% - 5px)"
              fxLayoutGap="5px grid"
              *ngFor="let component of package.components | slice: 0:9"
              src="../../assets/component-logos/{{ component }}.svg"
              onerror="this.src='../../assets/component-logos/component-placeholder.svg';"
              title="{{ component }}"
            />
```

Is there anyway to follow this formatting with flex layout:

[image: Format I want]

Obviously I have one less Icon than the formatting I want but the concept is to freely adjust the grid to whatever format I want (Like if there are 7 icons, put the last two under the 2nd and 4th icon etc...) **Ultimately, I want the icons to line up under each other**

Comment: Do you need to use the @angular/flex-layout package, could you just use vanilla CSS/SASS?

Comment: @WillD would say yes due to the rest of the project using it as well. How would you fix this with css?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

With CSS/SASS:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 195px;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

img:nth-child(-n+5) {
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

img:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}

img:nth-child(5) {
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</nav>
```